# Complex Aggregation Query in MongoDB Compass

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

Aggregation Pipeline in MongoDB Compass.

The pipeline will fetch today's dayOfWeek from the createdOn Column.
Then it will count the number of bookings per hour per businessSubType for the last month's every week day.

For example.
Today is Friday, 29th.
The pipeline should fetch the booking count per hour per business subtype for each friday in the last 4/5 weeks.
i.e. friday 22nd, friday 15th, friday 8th and friday 1st.

After this is done, The pipline will get the average of each hour for the last four fridays and store it somewhere for each hour.

So the output will look like
Hour - Average Hour Booking for last 4 fridays - Business SubType
1 Hour - 0 Booking - Flight.
2 Hour - 3 Booking - Hotel

In short, I want to get the average bookings for each businessSubType for each hour for the past month with the same DayOfWeek.

This is the code I am working with but it gives out same average and same totalBooking count.

```
`[
  {
    $addFields: {
      currentDayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: new Date() }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      createdOn: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date(),
      },
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          { $dayOfWeek: "$createdOn" },
          "$currentDayOfWeek"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      hour: { $hour: "$createdOn" },
      businessSubType: 1,
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        hour: "$hour",
        businessSubType: "$businessSubType",
      },
      totalBookings: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        businessSubType: "$_id.businessSubType",
        hour: "$_id.hour",
      },
      monthlyAverage: { $avg: "$totalBookings" },
      totalBookings: { $sum: "$totalBookings" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      hour: "$_id.hour",
      businessSubType: "$_id.businessSubType",
      monthlyAverage: 1,
      totalBookings: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      hour: 1
    }
  }
]`
```

Can you please help me fix this Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

as per your code have issue with calculating the daterange:

Here is the updated code with highlights of the `added code` or `modified` or `removed` one

```
[
  { $addFields: { currentDayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: new Date() } } },

  {
    $match: {
      createdOn: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: new Date()
      },
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          { $dayOfWeek: "$createdOn" },
          "$currentDayOfWeek"
        ]
      }
    }
  },

  {
    $project: {
      hour: { $hour: "$createdOn" },
      businessSubType: 1,
      week: { $week: "$createdOn" }  // <-- ADDED: Extracting the week of the year
    }
  },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        week: "$week",  // <-- ADDED: Grouping by week as well
        hour: "$hour",
        businessSubType: "$businessSubType"
      },
      bookingsForTheHour: { $sum: 1 }  // <-- CHANGED: Renamed from "totalBookings" to "bookingsForTheHour" for clarity of variable what it's doing
    }
  },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        hour: "$_id.hour",
        businessSubType: "$_id.businessSubType"
      },
      monthlyAverage: { $avg: "$bookingsForTheHour" }  // <-- CHANGED: Now taking average of the bookings for the hour
    }
  },

  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      hour: "$_id.hour",
      businessSubType: "$_id.businessSubType",
      monthlyAverage: 1  // <-- REMOVED: The totalBookings field, since it's not required
    }
  },

  {
    $sort: {
      businessSubType: 1,  // <-- ADDED: Sorting by businessSubType as well for better organization of result
      hour: 1
    }
  }
]
```

Try this one.